# ELASTICSEARCH - Recommendations to modify cluster size in ElastiCloud

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this error in Elastic CLoud:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Validation Failed: 1: this action would add [6] total shards, but this cluster currently has [2000]/[2000] maximum shards open;')
```

It is posible to modify the settings cluster in **cluster.max_shards_per_node.** in Elastic Cloud?

Do you recommend other solutions than modifying the size of the cluster?

Comment: its been really long time, would be great if you can provide update or ask follow up questions you may have

Answer (score 2):

you had the max shards configuration set as `2000` and looks like you are creating the new index which will have total 6 shards(including primary and replica) shards.

You can increase the total number of shards in a cluster if you have resources to handle it, the default is 1000 shards per cluster.

Another option is, if you have an unused index, you can delete them and free some shards in your cluster.

Comment: It should be 1000 shards per node, not cluster. "max_shards_per_node": "1000"